# Python - force a task to run only on single instance of multi-instance flask application

Tags: python, flask, instance, schedule, multiple-instances

I have a flask application running on a 3 instance. I have a scheduled job that runs every 5 minutes in this flask app but the problem is it runs on every instance. I want this scheduled job to run in a single instance.

```
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)

def sometask():
    """ this job will be scheduled for every 5 mins using scheduler"""

@app.route("/health")
def index():
#some logic
    pass
```

I want to schedule this job in such a way that it should run only on single instance.This will be an asynchronous call

Comment: And how do you "schedule" that job ?

Comment: using schedule module of python

Comment: Then you have to use some per-instance setting telling your process whether it should or not schedule this job - config file, env var or such + a test on this setting before calling the scheduler. The other obvious solution being to use the system's own scheduler (ie cron) so you only configure your crontab on one instance.

Comment: Could you please explain more ?